# Options for storing json data in a local db in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, local-database

I have a local browser application which downloads json data from an API. I need to store this data in the browser so that I can compare between the local version and the remote version if there is a change in remote version.

In the past, I have used localStorage for storing data using JSON.stringify to convert the objects to localStorage. But here, the data structures are more  complex and i have a few different types of json objects to store. I see that Chrome lists IndexedDB and WebSQL as storage options apart from localStorage. What options do I have to store data which can be more than 5 MB, which has to be persisted across sessions?

P.S. I did a search on stackoverflow and read through a few posts, but could not find any info that answers my question. I also checked out MDN which lists IndexedDB as an option, but it looks quite complex. I would be happy to see if there are any other options which has a simple usability like LocalStorage. What I am building is not a client-facing application, it is for a quick prototype and hence speed and ease of use would be more important than the support for transactions, etc. available in IndexedDB

Comment: For large data, IndexedDB is probably your best choice

Comment: Thank you. I am going through the tutorials for IndexedDB - looks promising, but quite complex :)

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying. Feel free to use something like localForage, which is (among other things) a much simpler IndexedDB wrapper

Comment: @CertainPerformance, wow - this is exactly what I was looking for. Great find. Thank you so much